# Security and use actions in CakePHP

Tags: url, cakephp, action

I'm new to cakephp, I'm doing a web application in cakephp 2.3.5, my application has several controllers with corresponding models in each controller. I have actions with their respective views, and other actions that are simply no view functions that are used by other actions.

I have two questions:

- One, of such actions is to remove an entity, is there any way that the user does not execute its actions through the browser by entering the URL (eg ... / estudiantes/delete/6)?, Meaning that only actions can launch web browsing.
- Two, I have several user page belongs to a different role, of course there will be action in which a specific profile can not use and others who, for this I use the function "IsAuthorized" on each controller, controlling every action and seeing the user and the role it plays using the session, would it be right?

Comment: i would've help you but i dont speak spanish...

Answer (score 1):

First question: yes, just change the delete action to protected or private and only other actions within your controller can access that. Or, if you're trying to use it with ajax or post, add this in the delete action

```
public function delete($id=null) {
   if ($this->request->is('ajax') || $this->request->is('post'))
        //do delete
   else
       //redirect or throw error or sad face
}
```

Second question: yes.
Or you could use plugins, like ACL.